# Shortening a function using a dictionary of functions?

Tags: python

How do I simplify the part were I am counting the h1, h2 - can I use some kind of dictionary to make it shorter?

```
cards = ['1t', '2t', '3t', '4t', '5t', '6t', '7t', '8t', '9t', '10t', '11t', '12t', '13t',
         '1k', '2k', '3k', '4k', '5k', '6k', '7k', '8k', '9k', '10k', '11k', '12k', '13k',
         '1s', '2s', '3s', '4s', '5s', '6s', '7s', '8s', '9s', '10s', '11s', '12s', '13s',
         '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p', '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p', '12p', '13p']

winn = {0: 'nothing', 1: 'one pair', 2: 'two pairs', 3: 'three of a kind', 4: 'straight', 5: 'flush',
        6: 'full house', 7: 'four of a kind', 8: 'straight flush', 9: 'royal flush'}

from random import choice


def hands():
    hand1, hand2 = [], []
    for i in range(5):
        x = choice(cards)
        hand1.append(x)
        cards.remove(x)
        y = choice(cards)
        hand2.append(y)
        cards.remove(y)
    return hand1, hand2


def check_royal_flush(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    if check_flush(hand) and check_straight(hand) and set(num) == {1, 10, 11, 12, 13}:
        return True
    return False


def check_straight_flush(hand):
    if check_flush(hand) and check_straight(hand):
        return True
    return False


def check_four_of_a_kind(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {1, 4}:
        return True
    return False


def check_full_house(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {2, 3}:
        return True
    return False


def check_flush(hand):
    suits = [i[1] if len(i) < 3 else i[2] for i in hand]
    if len(set(suits)) == 1:
        return True
    return False


def check_straight(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if sum(nn) == 5 and (max(num) - min(num) == 4):
        return True
    else:
        if set(num) == {1, 10, 11, 12, 13}:  # sprawdzanie dla asa
            return True
    return False


def check_three_of_a_kind(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {1, 3}:
        return True
    return False


def check_two_pairs(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {1, 2} and sum(nn) == 9:
        return True
    return False


def check_one_pair(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {1, 2} and sum(nn) == 7:
        return True
    return False


def check_winner():
    hand1 = hands()[0]
    hand2 = hands()[1]
    print(f"player one hand{hand1}")
    print(end="\n")
    print(f"player two hand{hand2}", end='\n')
    print(end="\n")
    h1, h2 = 0, 0
    num1 = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand1]
    num2 = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand2]
    if check_royal_flush(hand1):
        h1 = 9
    if check_royal_flush(hand2):
        h2 = 9
    elif check_straight_flush(hand1):
        h1 = 8
    elif check_straight_flush(hand2):
        h2 = 8
    elif check_four_of_a_kind(hand1):
        h1 = 7
    elif check_four_of_a_kind(hand2):
        h2 = 7
    elif check_full_house(hand1):
        h1 = 6
    elif check_full_house(hand2):
        h2 = 6
    elif check_flush(hand1):
        h1 = 5
    elif check_flush(hand2):
        h2 = 5
    elif check_straight(hand1):
        h1 = 4
    elif check_straight(hand2):
        h2 = 4
    elif check_three_of_a_kind(hand1):
        h1 = 3
    elif check_three_of_a_kind(hand2):
        h2 = 3
    elif check_two_pairs(hand1):
        h1 = 2
    elif check_two_pairs(hand2):
        h2 = 2
    elif check_one_pair(hand1):
        h1 = 1
    elif check_one_pair(hand2):
        h2 = 1
    else:
        h1 = 0
        h2 = 0

    if h1 > h2:
        return f"player one wins, with  hand {hand1} he had {winn[h1]}, player two with hand {hand2} had {winn[h2]}"
    elif h1 < h2:
        return f"player two wins, with  hand {hand2} he  had {winn[h2]}, player one with hand {hand1} had {winn[h1]}"
    elif h1 == h2 == 0:
        if max(num1) > sum(num2):
            return f"player one wins, with  hand {hand1} he had higher card, player two with hand {hand2} had {winn[h2]}"
        else:
            return f"player two wins, with  hand {hand2} he had higher card, player one with hand {hand1} had {winn[h1]}"
    elif h1 == h2:
        if sum(num1) > sum(num2):
            return f"player one wins, with  hand {hand1} he had {winn[h1]} with higher cards, player two with hand {hand2} had {winn[h2]}"
        else:
            return f"player two wins, with  hand {hand2} he had {winn[h2]} with higher cards, player one with hand {hand1} had {winn[h1]}"


print(check_winner())
```

Comment: Yes. It's usually possible to make code shorter, and you can use a dictionary. But on StackOverflow you should ask more specific answers. Maybe this question fits better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 1):

```py
if check_royal_flush(hand1):
        h1 = 9
    ...
    else:
        h1 = 0
        h2 = 0
```

may be changed to:

```py
checkers = (
  check_royal_flush,
  check_straight_flush,
  check_four_of_a_kind,
  check_full_house,
  check_flush,
  check_straight,
  check_three_of_a_kind,
  check_two_pairs,
  check_one_pair 
)

def check_winner():
  ...
  result = {"h1": 0, "h2": 0}
  for result_key, hand in (("h1", hand1), ("h2", hand2)):
    score = len(checkers)
    for checker in checkers:
      if checker(hand):
        result[result_key] = score
        break
      score -= 1
  ...
```

Comment: this will not work in all cases. You cannot break from the loop because there might be more than one matches (a royal flush is also a single pair). If you break you will only find the first matching pattern, not the best rated.

Comment: Yep. I edited answer (reverse tuple). We have to start from bigger score combination to be able break.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could list functions and loop over them, using the `.get` method to set the default value to `0`.

```
cards = ['1t', '2t', '3t', '4t', '5t', '6t', '7t', '8t', '9t', '10t', '11t', '12t', '13t',
         '1k', '2k', '3k', '4k', '5k', '6k', '7k', '8k', '9k', '10k', '11k', '12k', '13k',
         '1s', '2s', '3s', '4s', '5s', '6s', '7s', '8s', '9s', '10s', '11s', '12s', '13s',
         '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p', '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p', '12p', '13p']

winn = {0: 'nothing', 1: 'one pair', 2: 'two pairs', 3: 'three of a kind', 4: 'straight', 5: 'flush',
        6: 'full house', 7: 'four of a kind', 8: 'straight flush', 9: 'royal flush'}

from random import choice


def hands():
    hand1, hand2 = [], []
    for i in range(5):
        x = choice(cards)
        hand1.append(x)
        cards.remove(x)
        y = choice(cards)
        hand2.append(y)
        cards.remove(y)
    return hand1, hand2


def check_royal_flush(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    if check_flush(hand) and check_straight(hand) and set(num) == {1, 10, 11, 12, 13}:
        return True
    return False


def check_straight_flush(hand):
    if check_flush(hand) and check_straight(hand):
        return True
    return False


def check_four_of_a_kind(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {1, 4}:
        return True
    return False


def check_full_house(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {2, 3}:
        return True
    return False


def check_flush(hand):
    suits = [i[1] if len(i) < 3 else i[2] for i in hand]
    if len(set(suits)) == 1:
        return True
    return False


def check_straight(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if sum(nn) == 5 and (max(num) - min(num) == 4):
        return True
    else:
        if set(num) == {1, 10, 11, 12, 13}:  # sprawdzanie dla asa
            return True
    return False


def check_three_of_a_kind(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {1, 3}:
        return True
    return False


def check_two_pairs(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {1, 2} and sum(nn) == 9:
        return True
    return False


def check_one_pair(hand):
    num = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand]
    nn = [num.count(i) for i in num]
    if set(nn) == {1, 2} and sum(nn) == 7:
        return True
    return False


def check_winner():
    hand1 = hands()[0]
    hand2 = hands()[1]
    print(f"player one hand{hand1}")
    print(end="\n")
    print(f"player two hand{hand2}", end='\n')
    print(end="\n")
    h1, h2 = 0, 0
    num1 = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand1]
    num2 = [int(i[0]) if len(i) < 3 else int(i[0:2]) for i in hand2]
    
    funcs = {check_royal_flush:9,check_straight_flush:8,check_four_of_a_kind:7,check_full_house:6,check_flush:5,check_straight:4,check_three_of_a_kind:3,check_two_pairs:2,check_one_pair:1}
    for func in (check_royal_flush, check_straight_flush, check_four_of_a_kind, check_full_house, check_flush, check_straight, check_three_of_a_kind, check_two_pairs, check_one_pair):
        if func(hand1):
            h1 = funcs.get(func,0)
        elif func(hand2):
            h2 = funcs.get(func,0)
    if h1 > h2:
        return f"player one wins, with  hand {hand1} he had {winn[h1]}, player two with hand {hand2} had {winn[h2]}"
    elif h1 < h2:
        return f"player two wins, with  hand {hand2} he  had {winn[h2]}, player one with hand {hand1} had {winn[h1]}"
    elif h1 == h2 == 0:
        if max(num1) > sum(num2):
            return f"player one wins, with  hand {hand1} he had higher card, player two with hand {hand2} had {winn[h2]}"
        else:
            return f"player two wins, with  hand {hand2} he had higher card, player one with hand {hand1} had {winn[h1]}"
    elif h1 == h2:
        if sum(num1) > sum(num2):
            return f"player one wins, with  hand {hand1} he had {winn[h1]} with higher cards, player two with hand {hand2} had {winn[h2]}"
        else:
            return f"player two wins, with  hand {hand2} he had {winn[h2]} with higher cards, player one with hand {hand1} had {winn[h1]}"


print(check_winner())
```

Comment: Have you tested it? For a royal flush e.g. this will rate it as one pair, because that one is checked last. With this code you will not be able to find the maximum score but the last matching one.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like the following:

```
a_list = [
    (check_one_pair, 1),
    (check_two_pairs, 2),
    ...
    (check_royal_flush, 9)
]
h1, h2 = 0, 0
for func, score in a_list:
    if func(hand1):
        h1 = max(h1, score)
    if func(hand2):
        h2 = max(h2, score)
```

It does not use a dictionary but a list of tuples, because the mapping introduced by a dictionary is not needed for just iterating.